# Automatic Push Notification from rss (or Json) feed

Tags: ios, json, xcode, rss, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way to automaticaly check for new feeds in RSS (or Json) link and send the push notification of this new feed ?

Thank you !

Comment: @bllakjakk Thank you for your answer I tried your answer but i still didn't find solution ! I need a program that refresh feed every 5 min (for exemple) in the background and if there Is some new feed he is going to send a notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use apple's background task for timely fetching the rss content.
And then use the local notification to show push message.

Fetch your RSS in the following function that should be defined in APPDelegate

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"Fetch started");

    NSLog(@"Fetch completed");
}
```

You can set the interval using

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
    return true;
}
```

You can follow the blow for detailed understanding:
http://www.devfright.com/ios-7-background-app-refresh-tutorial/

Comment: Thank you for your answer I tried your answer but i still didn't find solution ! I need a program that refresh feed every 5 min (for exemple) in the background and if there Is some new feed he is going to send a notification

Answer (score 0):

Parse is that program.

Head out, check and implement the Push Notification SDK from:

https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

After you configured it, check out section 6 of the link to configure it with you REST API / database with your JSONs.

I don't know much about how REST works but this may help you:

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/REST

I'm pretty sure Parse is the way to go. Hope I helped you!

Comment: Thank you but it is not what I am looking for ! I need a program that check new feed permanently and send notification when we have a new feed

Comment: The problem is that the database is not in parse ! I am using a Json api of a website.

Comment: Can you just tell me how can I connect a Json feed to parse ?

Comment: I've read the documentation but it doesn't allow to check external feed it only works if your feed is in parse :/

Comment: It may not check, but you surely can add your posts to Parse and after that it will check.